# AJAX Won't return value from web api c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple web api created in C# which a method that returns a string

```
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Welcome Web API online";
    }
```

I am now calling it via javascript, It successfully hit the doe however it won't return any data, it always falls to error function,

```
var url = "https://localhost:44381/api/accounts";

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

Checking the console log, it shows:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44381/api/accounts?

Please enlighten me.

Comment: You need to enable CORS and set a list of allowed hosts, this will allow your backend to receive requests from different hosts.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://jonhilton.net/cross-origin-request-blocked/

Comment: @Sahil great help thanks:)

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk got it.. now i understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use  Ajax, angular etc to access a URL that has different origin then CORS (Cross-origin-request-sharing) needs to be handled at different origin side.
Past below code in your web api project. In **Global.asax.cs** file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

My be helpful to you.It works for me.

Comment: thanks! it works... great solution, without having nuget packages